# Stream PCM audio File via ezstream to icecast

Tags: audio, audio-streaming, pcm, icecast

I would like to know if i can stream i PCM audio file via ezstream to icecast :

My ezstream config file :

```
<ezstream>
<url>http://127.0.0.1:8000/myRadio</url>
<sourcepassword>hackme</sourcepassword> 
<format>MP3</format> 
<filename>C:\Users\HP\Downloads\ezstream-0.5.6-win32\test\playlist.txt</filename> 
<stream_once>1</stream_once> 
<svrinfoname>AAA</svrinfoname> 
<svrinfourl>http://test.ma</svrinfourl> 
<svrinfogenre>Software Developpement</svrinfogenre> 
<svrinfodescription>DDDD</svrinfodescription> 
<svrinfobitrate>128</svrinfobitrate> 
<svrinfochannels>2</svrinfochannels> 
<svrinfosamplerate>44100</svrinfosamplerate>
<svrinfopublic>1</svrinfopublic> 

    <reencode>
    <enable>1</enable>
    <encdec>
        <format>MP3</format>
        <match>.mp3</match>
        <encode>lame -r -s 44.1 - -</encode>
    </encdec>
    </reencode> 
    </ezstream>
```

Thank you

Comment: have you tried **anything** so far?

Comment: i'm new to icecast and ezstream. i succefuly stream some MP3 files to my radio server (icecast), but i don't know how can i stream a PCM file !
When i tried to convert my PCM audio file to MP3 using LAME, it work perfectly with command line based.

Any idea @thefiloe ?

Answer (score 0):

As of version 0.5.6 ezstream supports MP3, Ogg Vorbis and Ogg Theora